# Loop in list - selecting multiple item in a list

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

Good day everyone,

In brief, I have a list that populates a list of arrays through JSON data. Upon click, it takes users to a single item activity, which essentially provides more information about that particular item. Now I would want the user to do that up to three times. In other words, until the user has clicked on three different items on the list of arrays, it would continuously prompt them to select additional item on the list until they have selected 3 item. Once 3 items have been selected, the user would be redirected to another activity page.

Below is the code for list of arrays activity page

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", list_item_name);
                intent.putExtra("list_item_description", list_item_description);
                intent.putExtra("list_item_price",list_item_price);

                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the single item activity

```
public class EventSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("list_item_description");
        list_item_price = i.getStringExtra("list_item_price");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView txtprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtdescription.setText(list_item_description);
        txtprice.setText(list_item_price);


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, and I appreciate all assistance.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this [tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/)

Comment: ok what is happening now?

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. @Kerppag I have looked into the tutorial, and it was quite helpful.

Comment: @Aniruddha what is happening is as follow: when the activity page is launched a list of arrays of items is populated through JSON data, in other words generated from the internet. When a user clicks on an array of item (picture, title, description), it takes them to a page that provides more information about that item. My intent is that they would have to go through this process three times before being taken to another activity. However, I am still trying to figure it out.